# How to cancel a download in cordova?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using `$cordovafiletransfer.download()` method to download. I would like to know how can I cancel a download when download is in progress. I  have mentioned my code here:

```
 $scope.fileDownload = function(url) {

        $cordovaToast.showLongBottom('Your download has started');
        $scope.progressbar={"display":"block"};
        $scope.progressvalue=2;
        $scope.downloadbtn="downloadbtnon"

        var filename = url.split("/").pop();

        var targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + 'Podcasts' + filename;

        $scope.loading = "font-size:20px;display:inline-block;stroke:#fff;";
        $scope.isDisabled = true;
        $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, {}, true).then(function(result) {
            //console.log('Success');
            $scope.hasil = 'Save file on ' + targetPath + ' success!';
            $scope.mywallpaper = targetPath;
            $scope.isDisabled = false;
            $scope.loading = "display:none;";
            $scope.progressbar={"display":"none"};
            $scope.downloadbtn="downloadbtnoff"
            // $timeout(function() {

            // }, 1000);
            $cordovaToast.showLongBottom('Download completed(' + targetPath + ')');
        }, function(error) {
            console.log('Error downloading file');
            console.log(error);
            $scope.hasil = 'Error downloading file...';
            $cordovaToast.showLongBottom('Download failed.. Please try again');
            $scope.progressbar={"display":"none"};
            $scope.downloadbtn="downloadbtnoff"
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.isDisabled = false;
                $scope.loading = "display:none;";
            }, 1000);
        }, function(progress) {
            console.log('progress');
            $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
            $scope.progressvalue=$scope.downloadProgress;
            $scope.progressbar={"display":"block"};
            $scope.downloadbtn="downloadbtnon"
            // var downcountString = $scope.downloadProgress.toFixed();
            // console.log('downcountString');
            // $scope.downloadCount = downcountString;
        });
    }
```

for cancelling download I have tried this `$cordovaFileTransfer.abort();` but I am getting an error like `Type error undefined not defined`. Please any one help me to solve this issue.

Comment: i have fixed this issue friends by using this  var file=$cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, {}, true);file.abort();